# docker.bintray.io/jfrog/artifactory 7.18.6 version run failed

Tags: macos, docker, artifactory, apple-m1

I work with Apple M1 chip macbook pro. After i install the corresponding version of docker and run below command in terminal.

> softwareupdate --install-rosetta

I pull the latest oss version (7.18.6) of jfrog/artifactory, and create its container with

> docker run --name repo -d -p 8081:8081 -p 8082:8082 -p 8046:8046 -p 8049:8049 -p 8070:8070 docker.bintray.io/jfrog/artifactory-oss

I saw an error exception in the docker LOGS tab as below, any ideas?

```
Preparing to run Artifactory in Docker
Running as uid=1030(artifactory) gid=1030(artifactory)
Dockerfile for this image can found inside the container.
To view the Dockerfile: 'cat /docker/artifactory-oss/Dockerfile.artifactory'.
Copying Artifactory bootstrap files
2021-05-16T05:06:23.000Z [shell] [INFO ] [] [installerCommon.sh:1507       ] [main] - Checking open files and processes limits
2021-05-16T05:06:23.000Z [shell] [INFO ] [] [installerCommon.sh:1510       ] [main] - Current max open files is 1048576
2021-05-16T05:06:23.000Z [shell] [INFO ] [] [installerCommon.sh:1521       ] [main] - Current max open processes is unlimited
Database connection check failed Could not determine database type
2021-05-16T05:06:24.000Z [shell] [INFO ] [] [installerCommon.sh:1588       ] [main] - Testing directory /opt/jfrog/artifactory/var has read/write permissions for user id 1030
2021-05-16T05:06:24.000Z [shell] [INFO ] [] [installerCommon.sh:1603       ] [main] - Permissions for /opt/jfrog/artifactory/var are good
2021-05-16T05:06:26.000Z [shell] [INFO ] [] [installerCommon.sh:3364       ] [main] - Setting JF_SHARED_NODE_ID to 16a00d6149c7
2021-05-16T05:06:26.000Z [shell] [INFO ] [] [installerCommon.sh:3364       ] [main] - Setting JF_SHARED_NODE_IP to 172.17.0.2
2021-05-16T05:06:27.000Z [shell] [INFO ] [] [installerCommon.sh:3364       ] [main] - Setting JF_SHARED_NODE_NAME to 16a00d6149c7
2021-05-16T05:06:31.000Z [shell] [INFO ] [] [artifactoryCommon.sh:315      ] [main] - Removing old custom drivers : /opt/jfrog/artifactory/app/artifactory/tomcat/lib/jf_*
2021-05-16T05:06:31.000Z [shell] [INFO ] [] [artifactoryCommon.sh:321      ] [main] - Copying /opt/jfrog/artifactory/var/bootstrap/artifactory/tomcat/lib/README.md to /opt/jfrog/artifactory/app/artifactory/tomcat/lib/jf_README.md
2021-05-16T05:06:32.000Z [shell] [INFO ] [] [artifactoryCommon.sh:148      ] [main] - Saving /opt/jfrog/artifactory/app/artifactory/tomcat/conf/server.xml as /opt/jfrog/artifactory/app/artifactory/tomcat/conf/server.xml.orig
2021-05-16T05:06:32.000Z [shell] [INFO ] [] [artifactoryCommon.sh:156      ] [main] - Using Tomcat template to generate : /opt/jfrog/artifactory/app/artifactory/tomcat/conf/server.xml
2021-05-16T05:06:33.000Z [shell] [INFO ] [] [artifactoryCommon.sh:807      ] [main] - Resolved ${artifactory.port||8081} to default value : 8081
2021-05-16T05:06:33.000Z [shell] [INFO ] [] [artifactoryCommon.sh:807      ] [main] - Resolved ${artifactory.tomcat.connector.maxThreads||200} to default value : 200
2021-05-16T05:06:34.000Z [shell] [INFO ] [] [artifactoryCommon.sh:807      ] [main] - Resolved ${artifactory.tomcat.maintenanceConnector.port||8091} to default value : 8091
2021-05-16T05:06:35.000Z [shell] [INFO ] [] [artifactoryCommon.sh:807      ] [main] - Resolved ${artifactory.tomcat.maintenanceConnector.maxThreads||5} to default value : 5
2021-05-16T05:06:35.000Z [shell] [INFO ] [] [artifactoryCommon.sh:807      ] [main] - Resolved ${artifactory.tomcat.maintenanceConnector.acceptCount||5} to default value : 5
2021-05-16T05:06:36.000Z [shell] [INFO ] [] [artifactoryCommon.sh:807      ] [main] - Resolved ${access.http.port||8040} to default value : 8040
2021-05-16T05:06:37.000Z [shell] [INFO ] [] [artifactoryCommon.sh:807      ] [main] - Resolved ${access.tomcat.connector.maxThreads||50} to default value : 50
2021-05-16T05:06:38.000Z [shell] [INFO ] [] [systemYamlHelper.sh:515       ] [main] - Resolved JF_PRODUCT_HOME (/opt/jfrog/artifactory) from environment variable
2021-05-16T05:06:38.000Z [shell] [INFO ] [] [artifactoryCommon.sh:807      ] [main] - Resolved ${shared.tomcat.workDir||/opt/jfrog/artifactory/var/work/artifactory/tomcat} to default value : /opt/jfrog/artifactory/var/work/artifactory/tomcat
========================
JF Environment variables
========================
JF_SHARED_NODE_NAME                 : 16a00d6149c7
JF_ROUTER_TOPOLOGY_LOCAL_REQUIREDSERVICETYPES : jfrt,jfac,jfmd,jffe
JF_PRODUCT_HOME                     : /opt/jfrog/artifactory
JF_SYSTEM_YAML                      : /opt/jfrog/artifactory/var/etc/system.yaml
JF_PRODUCT_DATA_INTERNAL            : /var/opt/jfrog/artifactory
JF_ARTIFACTORY_PID                  : /opt/jfrog/artifactory/app/run/artifactory.pid
JF_SHARED_NODE_IP                   : 172.17.0.2
JF_SHARED_NODE_ID                   : 16a00d6149c7
JF_ARTIFACTORY_USER                 : artifactory
Using default router's certificate and private key
Starting router...
router not running. Proceed to start it up.
router started. PID: 6119
Starting metadata...
2021-05-16T05:06:42.884Z [jfrou] [INFO ] [73753b2448c89fe0] [bootstrap.go:76               ] [main                ] - Router (jfrou) service initialization started. Version: 7.18.2-1 Revision: 6804b8fc8cccabfa14876d26a92e2fa20a59e232 PID: 6119 Home: /opt/jfrog/artifactory
2021-05-16T05:06:42.886Z [jfrou] [INFO ] [73753b2448c89fe0] [bootstrap.go:79               ] [main                ] - JFrog Router IP: 172.17.0.2
JF_METADATA_ACCESSCLIENT_URL: http://localhost:8081/access
metadata started. PID: 6390
[DEBUG] Resolved system configuration file path: /opt/jfrog/artifactory/var/etc/system.yaml
[TRACE] Config key not set for aws secret (metadata.database.secretsManagerAlias)
Starting frontend...
frontend not running. Proceed to start it up.
frontend started. PID: 6652
2021-05-16T05:06:46.000Z [shell] [INFO ] [] [installerCommon.sh:1183       ] [main] - Redirection is set to false. Skipping catalina log redirection
2021-05-16T05:06:47.895Z [jfrou] [INFO ] [73753b2448c89fe0] [security_keys.go:149          ] [main                ] - Master key is missing. Pending for 5 seconds with 2m0s timeout
2021-05-16T05:06:49.295Z [jfmd ] [INFO ] [13f3350f788f6593] [security_keys.go:149          ] [main                ] - Master key is missing. Pending for 5 seconds with 2m0s timeout [init]
2021-05-16T05:06:52.001Z [jffe ] [INFO ] [                ] [                              ] [main                ] - frontend (jffe) service initialization started. Version: 1.18.6 Revision: 10000006 PID: 6922 Home: /opt/jfrog/artifactory
2021-05-16T05:06:52.031Z [jffe ] [INFO ] [                ] [                              ] [main                ] - attempting pinging artifactory for 180 retires and 1.0s interval for total of 3 minutes
2021-05-16T05:06:52.897Z [jfrou] [INFO ] [73753b2448c89fe0] [security_keys.go:149          ] [main                ] - Master key is missing. Pending for 10 seconds with 2m0s timeout
2021-05-16T05:06:54.304Z [jfmd ] [INFO ] [13f3350f788f6593] [security_keys.go:149          ] [main                ] - Master key is missing. Pending for 10 seconds with 2m0s timeout [init]
2021-05-16T05:06:57.194Z [jfrt ] [INFO ] [dd1cb5e20ec4a7f3] [o.a.c.h.HaNodeProperties:65   ] [ocalhost-startStop-2] - Artifactory is running in non-clustered mode.
2021-05-16T05:06:57.262Z [jfrt ] [INFO ] [dd1cb5e20ec4a7f3] [tifactoryHomeConfigListener:85] [ocalhost-startStop-2] - Resolved Home: '/opt/jfrog/artifactory
2021-05-16T05:06:57.902Z [jfrou] [INFO ] [73753b2448c89fe0] [security_keys.go:149          ] [main                ] - Master key is missing. Pending for 15 seconds with 2m0s timeout
2021-05-16T05:06:59.008Z [jfrt ] [ERROR] [dd1cb5e20ec4a7f3] [tifactoryHomeConfigListener:55] [ocalhost-startStop-2] - Failed initializing Home. Caught exception: 
java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to int file watcher.
    at org.jfrog.config.watch.FileWatcher.<init>(FileWatcher.java:78)
    at org.jfrog.config.watch.FileWatcher.<init>(FileWatcher.java:59)
    at org.jfrog.config.watch.FileWatcher.create(FileWatcher.java:55)
    at org.jfrog.config.ConfigurationManagerImpl.<init>(ConfigurationManagerImpl.java:82)
    at org.jfrog.config.ConfigurationManagerImpl.create(ConfigurationManagerImpl.java:63)
    at org.artifactory.lifecycle.webapp.servlet.BasicConfigurationManager.<init>(BasicConfigurationManager.java:84)
    at org.artifactory.lifecycle.webapp.servlet.ArtifactoryHomeConfigListener.getBasicConfigManagers(ArtifactoryHomeConfigListener.java:78)
    at org.artifactory.lifecycle.webapp.servlet.ArtifactoryHomeConfigListener.contextInitialized(ArtifactoryHomeConfigListener.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4705)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5171)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:743)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:719)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:705)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor(HostConfig.java:606)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDescriptor.run(HostConfig.java:1766)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Function not implemented
    at java.base/sun.nio.fs.LinuxWatchService.<init>(LinuxWatchService.java:64)
    at java.base/sun.nio.fs.LinuxFileSystem.newWatchService(LinuxFileSystem.java:47)
    at org.jfrog.config.watch.FileWatcher.<init>(FileWatcher.java:74)
    ... 20 common frames omitted
2021-05-16T05:06:59.036Z [jfrt ] [ERROR] [dd1cb5e20ec4a7f3] [actoryContextConfigListener:92] [ocalhost-startStop-2] - Failed initializing Artifactory context: Artifactory home not initialized.
2021-05-16T05:06:59.307Z [jfmd ] [INFO ] [13f3350f788f6593] [security_keys.go:149          ] [main                ] - Master key is missing. Pending for 15 seconds with 2m0s timeout [init]
2021-05-16 05:07:00.865  WARN 6895 --- [kground-preinit] o.s.h.c.j.Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder    : For Jackson Kotlin classes support please add "com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-kotlin" to the classpath
2021-05-16 05:07:00.962 ERROR 6895 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed
java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to create logback file: /opt/jfrog/artifactory/var/etc/access/logback.xml
    at org.jfrog.app.context.JFrogApplicationContextInitializer.createLogbackFileIfMissing(JFrogApplicationContextInitializer.java:122) ~[jfrog-application-7.18.2.jar:na]
    at org.jfrog.app.context.JFrogApplicationContextInitializer.configureLogback(JFrogApplicationContextInitializer.java:102) ~[jfrog-application-7.18.2.jar:na]
    at org.jfrog.app.context.JFrogApplicationContextInitializer.initialize(JFrogApplicationContextInitializer.java:80) ~[jfrog-application-7.18.2.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.applyInitializers(SpringApplication.java:623) ~[spring-boot-2.1.16.RELEASE.jar:2.1.16.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.prepareContext(SpringApplication.java:367) ~[spring-boot-2.1.16.RELEASE.jar:2.1.16.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:311) ~[spring-boot-2.1.16.RELEASE.jar:2.1.16.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.run(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:151) ~[spring-boot-2.1.16.RELEASE.jar:2.1.16.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.createRootApplicationContext(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:131) ~[spring-boot-2.1.16.RELEASE.jar:2.1.16.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.onStartup(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:91) ~[spring-boot-2.1.16.RELEASE.jar:2.1.16.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.SpringServletContainerInitializer.onStartup(SpringServletContainerInitializer.java:172) ~[spring-web-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5160) ~[catalina.jar:8.5.63]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183) ~[catalina.jar:8.5.63]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:743) ~[catalina.jar:8.5.63]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:719) ~[catalina.jar:8.5.63]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:705) ~[catalina.jar:8.5.63]
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor(HostConfig.java:606) ~[catalina.jar:8.5.63]
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDescriptor.run(HostConfig.java:1766) ~[catalina.jar:8.5.63]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834) ~[na:na]
Caused by: java.net.MalformedURLException: no !/ found in url spec:file:/opt/jfrog/artifactory/app/artifactory/tomcat/webapps/access/WEB-INF/lib/netty-codec-http-4.1.53.Final.jar!/
    at java.base/java.net.JarURLConnection.parseSpecs(JarURLConnection.java:172) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.net.JarURLConnection.<init>(JarURLConnection.java:158) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.jar.JarURLConnection.<init>(JarURLConnection.java:81) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.jar.Handler.openConnection(Handler.java:41) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.net.URL.openConnection(URL.java:1074) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.core.io.support.PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver.doFindPathMatchingJarResources(PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver.java:591) ~[spring-core-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.core.io.support.PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver.findPathMatchingResources(PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver.java:510) ~[spring-core-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.core.io.support.PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver.getResources(PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver.java:284) ~[spring-core-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.jfrog.app.context.JFrogApplicationContextInitializer.inputStreamForLogbackXml(JFrogApplicationContextInitializer.java:129) ~[jfrog-application-7.18.2.jar:na]
    at org.jfrog.app.context.JFrogApplicationContextInitializer.createLogbackFileIfMissing(JFrogApplicationContextInitializer.java:119) ~[jfrog-application-7.18.2.jar:na]
    ... 21 common frames omitted
2021-05-16T05:07:01.575Z [jffe ] [INFO ] [                ] [                              ] [main                ] - pinging artifactory, attempt number 10
2021-05-16T05:07:01.599Z [jffe ] [INFO ] [                ] [                              ] [main                ] - pinging artifactory attempt number 10 failed with code : ECONNREFUSED
2021-05-16T05:07:02.915Z [jfrou] [INFO ] [73753b2448c89fe0] [security_keys.go:149          ] [main                ] - Master key is missing. Pending for 20 seconds with 2m0s timeout
2021-05-16T05:07:04.325Z [jfmd ] [INFO ] [13f3350f788f6593] [security_keys.go:149          ] [main                ] - Master key is missing. Pending for 20 seconds with 2m0s timeout [init]
2021-05-16T05:07:07.934Z [jfrou] [INFO ] [73753b2448c89fe0] [security_keys.go:149          ] [main                ] - Master key is missing. Pending for 25 seconds with 2m0s timeout
2021-05-16T05:07:09.350Z [jfmd ] [INFO ] [13f3350f788f6593] [security_keys.go:149          ] [main                ] - Master key is missing. Pending for 25 seconds with 2m0s timeout [init]
2021-05-16T05:07:11.873Z [jffe ] [INFO ] [                ] [                              ] [main                ] - pinging artifactory, attempt number 20
2021-05-16T05:07:11.893Z [jffe ] [INFO ] [                ] [                              ] [main                ] - pinging artifactory attempt number 20 failed with code : ECONNREFUSED
2021-05-16T05:07:12.958Z [jfrou] [INFO ] [73753b2448c89fe0] [security_keys.go:149          ] [main                ] - Master key is missing. Pending for 30 seconds with 2m0s timeout
2021-05-16T05:07:14.379Z [jfmd ] [INFO ] [13f3350f788f6593] [security_keys.go:149          ] [main                ] - Master key is missing. Pending for 30 seconds with 2m0s timeout [init]
2021-05-16T05:07:17.973Z [jfrou] [INFO ] [73753b2448c89fe0] [security_keys.go:149          ] [main                ] - Master key is missing. Pending for 35 seconds with 2m0s timeout
2021-05-16T05:07:19.406Z [jfmd ] [INFO ] [13f3350f788f6593] [security_keys.go:149          ] [main                ] - Master key is missing. Pending for 35 seconds with 2m0s timeout [init]
```